# Long words breaking layout. What about with HTML input in UTF-8?

Tags: html, line-breaks, words

Imagine if I have in a text something like [a href="this-is-a-very-big-link"]this is ok[/a] (switch < and > with [ and ])... And also this-is-a-very-big-word.

I need to cut the second case in two lines...

Notice wordwrap kills the link so it is not useful for solving this sort of problem.

Any idea?

Comment: What do you mean wordwrap kills the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CSS:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

Answer (score 0):

Decided to use the breakLongWords() function found on the www.php.net/wordwrap

I know using word-wrap: break-word; would be better, but as I tried right now I saw that Firefox doesn't implement it yet, so I guess I'll have to keep it on the server-side...